# QGis Print Composer: layer symbology not displayed

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer, display

Exactly the same as [this](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/2694) problem from way back, only I've had this from 1.8.0 to present (2.1.0 master).

Yay, symbols:
[image]

Boo: no symbols, cue MS Paint:
[image]

Anyone know why this might be or have the same problem?

Happens on Win7 & Ubuntu (& Xubuntu) 13.04.

---

This issue raised on hug.qis.org (and can be subscribed to) [here](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8651).

Comment: Have you just tried in 2.0?

Comment: Hi Nathan. @ctpult mentioned (below) about trying 2.0 also; I've not tried 2.0 but can confirm it works in 1.8. I don't have a 2.0 available... is that a stable beta which should be an option if I have master installed? Or is it a separate install? Thanks!

Comment: Get 2.0 from here http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: Thanks Nathan, sorry that that was an obvious question; I wasn't sure if it should also install the big beta releases by default. Given this, I'll mark this as solved, with the caveat that it's broken in 2.1.0 master - should I report this as a bug to hub.qgis.org?

Comment: Already exists, should have checked, sorry. Link added as edit to main question.

Comment: @NathanW - hopefully not to newbish a question: do you know whether adding the stable repository to my software sources SHOULD then allow concurrent installing of v2.0? I've already got the nightly software source, and trying to 'apt-get install qgis' just saying it's already current... Any thoughts? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with vector data on version 2.1.0 master but got it solved by opening the project with 2.0 version.

Comment: can confirm that it works fine in 1.8.0 also - good to know at least there's the fallback if required.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same thing with rasters.  I can't tell you why it happens but the solution is easy.  Simply remove the layer in question from the legend and then re-add it. Sometimes the 'Update item' button does the trick but not always.

Another quirk I've found is that sometimes it seems unresponsive if you try to change the text for the labels or the title.  The simplest way to work around that glitch is to change the layer title in the first tab of the layer properties (and it's probably best to change the label text in the style tab  of the layer properties while you're at it).  Then do the remove-and-add-again trick in the legend and all will be well.

This problem seems to be isolated to rasters and in particular when the raster is changed or added and a map is already open

Comment: thanks for the tip. Sadly mine's vector and this trick doesn't work. Boo!